# Ruby Thor::Actions get method behind a proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, thor

How i can execute get method from Thor::Actions behind a proxy?

Comment: That's a rather vague question, I don't really what a proxy is in that context too.

Comment: Internet proxy I suppose, I ran into the same problem, that means I can't use it or anything that depends on it in basically any educational institution.